# A Question On Indices Notation In General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, definition, differentiation

I am trying to make sense of this simple case in my book, but I am still baffled by the notation that is used in the indices with the commas and semicolons; I also do not understand how these are equivalent.

$$A_{\alpha;\beta}-A_{\beta;\alpha}=A_{\alpha,\beta}-A_{\beta,\alpha}$$

Comment: Please explain better the notation, or add a reference in which this notation is used, some (like me) may be not familiar with this notation

Comment: Which book? Which page?

Comment: The connection is presumably torsionfree.

Comment: Sean Carroll-Spacetime and Geometry: An Introduction to General Relativity, 2019 edition, Chapter 3, Page 152.

Comment: I think that the book probably explains the comma and semicolon notations somewhere, before page 152.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By definition:
\begin{align}\tag{1} A_{\mu,\nu} &\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}} \, A_{\mu} \equiv \partial_{\nu} \, A_{\mu}, \\[1ex]
\tag{2} A_{\mu;\nu} &\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}} \, A_{\mu} - \Gamma_{\nu \mu}^{\lambda} \, A_{\lambda} \equiv \nabla_{\nu} \, A_{\mu},\end{align}
If the connection is symetric: $\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\lambda} = \Gamma_{\nu \mu}^{\lambda}$ (Levi-Civita connection AKA Christoffel symbols, which means *no torsion*), then the antisymetric expression $A_{\mu;\nu} - A_{\nu;\mu}$ gives the same as $A_{\mu,\nu} - A_{\nu,\mu}$.

Comment: Just to be more precise, please don't take it as a critic, I completely understand the spirit of your answer. But the connection and the Christoffel symbols are two completely different objects, what you meant is that if you choose the Levi-Civita connection (as it is usually done in GR) then the Christoffel symbols are symmetric in the two "down" indices.

Answer (score 2):

The semikolon indicates a covariant derivative, in General Relativity only covariant derivatives transform like a tensor, therefore it is so important.

The simple comma in difference indicates a simple derivative.

the difference between covariant derivative and simple derivative is:

$$A_{a;b} = A_{a,b} - \Gamma^c_{ba} A_c$$

where $\Gamma$ stands for the Christoffel-symbols. See a.o.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols

On the basis of this formula it can be easily shown that

$$A_{a;b} -A_{b;a} = A_{a,b} - A_{b,a}$$

because the Christoffel-symbols are symmetric on the 2. and 3. index (if the torsion is zero).
Actually, in order to define a covariant derivative on a (pseudo)-Riemannian manifold an additional structure is required, the "connection". The Christoffel-symbols represent here the connection. 
However, for the computation of an exterior derivative of a one-form $A$
a connection is not required. Actually $ A_{a,b} - A_{b,a}$ represent the result of the exterior derivative of a one-form $A$ in components. 
The equality $A_{a;b} -A_{b;a} = A_{a,b} - A_{b,a}$ shows that an exterior derivative can be defined on a (pseudo)-Riemannian manifold without further structure introduced.